# Give the classes a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have a question about the class, and give the class a specific id.

For example I've got a html code like this:

```
<div class="test">text1</div>
<div class="test">text2</div>
<div class="test">text3</div>
<div class="test">text4</div>
<div class="test">text5</div>
```

My question is how can I add an id by each .test class.

I thought something like this in Jquery:

```
var i = 1;
$('.test').each(function(){
   $('.test').attr('id','id_'+i+'');
   i++
});
```

This doesn't work I think it's something with .closest() or .next()
to solve this problem.

Regards,

Frank

EDIT:

I solved the problem by myself the answer is:

```
    $('.test').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('class','test').attr('id','id_'+i+'');
        i++;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

No reason to make a counter, .each() comes with one built in.

```
$('.test').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('id','id_'+i+'');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` to refer to the current element the in callback function:

```
var i = 1;
$('.test').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('id','id_'+i);
   i++
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Much faster and simpler like this:

```
$('.test').each(function(i){
   this.id = 'id_' + i;
});
```

There's no need for `.attr()` when setting or getting the `id` of an element.

Or if you wanted the numbers to start with `1`, do this:

```
$('.test').each(function(i){
   this.id = 'id_' + (i + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path:

```
var i = 1;
$('.test').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('id','id_'+i+'');
   i++
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery instead:

```
var i, $test = $('.test'), tl = $test.length;
for (i = 0; i < tl; i++) {
   $test.eq(i).attr('id','id_'+i+'');
}
```

As `i` is incremented in the `for` loop, you select the specific element you want to give the `i` based `id` with `.eq(i)`.

Comment: Yes I know this option but didn't know about the .eq(i) function thank you for answering

Comment: that isn't jquery, it's javascript.

Comment: No offense, but this is a really bad way to do it. You're doing a DOM selection for `.test` twice for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: You're right, I whipped it out quick.  I'll cache it.  And it's a javascript look with a jQuery body...  semantics. UPDATE: edited to cache, thanks